# Completion of one Java cron after other cron is started

Tags: java, cron

I want something like `join` in multi-threading.  Completion of one cron after that other cron start the execution.

Comment: Why not just put a `CountDownLatch` between the two blocks of code?

Comment: When you say "cron", what do you mean? The actual *nix `cron(8)` program, or some Java library that implements cron-like functionality? If the latter, which library, and how are you invoking it.

Comment: "I want" is one thing. "What I have tried" is what _we_ want to know.

Comment: i am using the Quartz scheduler

Comment: OK, that's a start. Now how are you invoking it and/or defining your jobs? You'll find that the more details you provide, the better answers you get.

Comment: Also, do you *ever* want the second job to start independently of the first, or do you *always* want the second to be dependent on the first?

Comment: for invocation using the cron expression to trigger the cron for a given time,cron are dependent on each other

Comment: @ashishchaurasia - you haven't answered my question; I have no idea whether you're writing code to trigger the job or using a configuration file. If you want an answer, you're going to have to put some real effort into asking the question, and not expect people to pry the details of you. Please edit your question with the *exact* code/configuration that you're using to trigger the jobs. Also, please call them "jobs"; "cron" is simply a way to trigger jobs, and your misuse of the term is confusing.